# Comparing a number from one file and match it in in a file when it comes inside a string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two files. One contains only one column of random integers. 
1.dat :

```
    2
    4
    7
    9
```

Other file  (2.dat) contains the following:

```
    <event id="2">
    <rwgt>
    <wgt id="1">0.866665</wgt>
    <wgt id="2">0.866665</wgt>
    <event id="3">
    <rwgt>
    <wgt id="1">0.901111</wgt>
    <wgt id="2">0.901111</wgt>
    ....
```

I want to compare the each number of 1.dat to the number inside

```
    <event id=" "> tag
```

and when matching I want to have the number inside

```
    <wgt id="1"> </wgt> tag
```

I am using for the 1st file in my shell script

```
    #! /bin/bash
    while read first ; 
    do
    echo "$first"
    done < 1.dat
```

But inside the do loop I am still unable to incorporate the 2.dat file.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: At the moment it's not clear what you are trying to do. Could you [edit] your question to show us what the output would be for the example you've shown?

Comment: Hi, my goal is to have the number inside <wgt id="1"> </wgt> tag  (eg 0.866665) when any number of 1.dat (eg. 2) matches with <event id=" "> in 2.dat (eg <event id=" ">).  The two files that I have shown contain thousands of these patterns. Upto this portion my output will be .866665 (since there is only one such matching for number 2).

Comment: I your input file supposed to be valid XML? If it is, you could (and should) use an XML parser to get the values you're interested in. At the moment, it is missing a few closing tags.

Comment: Hi, this is a valid XML. Actually it contains some millions of lines. I have just showed here a little piece. It looks like this

        <event id="1000">
        <rwgt>
        <wgt id="1">0.923099</wgt>
        <wgt id="2">0.923099</wgt>
        <wgt id="3">0.923099</wgt>
         .....
        </rwgt>
        </event>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, if your real file was valid XML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <event id="2">
    <rwgt>
      <wgt id="1">0.866665</wgt>
      <wgt id="2">0.866665</wgt>
    </rwgt>
  </event>
  <event id="3">
    <rwgt>
      <wgt id="1">0.901111</wgt>
      <wgt id="2">0.901111</wgt>
    </rwgt>
  </event>
</root>
```

Then you could use an XML parser, such as xmllint to extract the value you were interested in:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read id; do
    val=$(xmllint --xpath "//event[@id='$id']//wgt[@id=1]/text()" 2.dat 2>/dev/null)
    [[ -n $val ]] && echo "$val"
done < 1.dat
```

Here I've used an xpath expression to get the text content of the `<wgt>` element with `id=1`, within the `<event>` element with a matching `id` to the value in the file. A message is printed to stderr if nothing is matched, so I've redirected it to `/dev/null` to suppress it.

Output:

```
0.866665
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read first
do
        if grep "<event id=\"$first\">" 2.dat
        then grep -A 2 "<event id=\"$first\">" 2.dat | tail -1 | sed 's/\(<wgt id=...>\|<\/wgt>\)//g'  >>output.dat
        fi
done < 1.dat

exit
```

This will output expected line to `./output.dat`

Comment: Hi, this is returning the last matching output i.e. for 9 of 1.dat.
So the output is coming  <wgt id="1">0.845824</wgt>. I want the number 0.845824. Also for each matching 2, 4, 7, 9 ... of 1.dat with corresponding <event id=" ">  2.dat.  Is that possible?

Comment: Ah ok. You need to output just the number in wgt tag corresponding to matched ids from 1.dat. I will edit this shortly. But what do you mean when you say "returning the last matching output i.e. for 9 of 1.dat." - The script I gave is running through all numbers in 1.dat  ? Maybe we have a different bash version.

Comment: Ok, now it should be correct. - I tested it, and it definitely runs through all numbers in 1.dat.
**GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**

Comment: Its running through all numbers but the sed is not working. Still getting the whole line instead of the numbers only. Probably because of my old bash version (version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11))!!

Comment: Yes, probably :-) I have tested it thoroughly.  Unless you have a difference in layout of 2.dat, i.e additional white spaces., can you tell me if your file is exactly as you have it in the question

Comment: <event id="1">
<rwgt> start with  no spacing
but   <wgt id="1 starts with 2 spaces.

Comment: Tested, works fine still, so you need to update bash. Are you able to?

Comment: I will not now risk of bash update now, sorry !!... I will try to modify (sed portion) what you have suggested.